# Conditional formatting with values ​in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[image]I wanted to use conditional formatting to paint the values ​​in red from the left table, only values ​​that are equal to the right table, but I'm not getting it, the values ​​just don't get red from the right table, what is going on ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula for Left table:

```
=COUNTIF($E$46:$G$48,A46)<>0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: also gave without using "<> 0". also if typing "<> 1" it counts values ​​that do not exist in the left table. I already knew how to use this formula, but I didn't know how to use it within conditional formatting. Thank you!